# Python subprocess is showing output in stderr

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, python-3.5

I created the following script to shutdown an Ubuntu machine after **X** minutes.

```
import subprocess

def execute_command(command):
    command = command.split()
    try:
        print(command)
        command_process = subprocess.run(command,
                                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = command_process.stdout.decode('utf-8')            
        output_message = "Command output: {}".format(output)
        error = command_process.stderr.decode('utf-8')            
        error_message = "Command error: {}".format(error)
        print(output_message)
        print(error_message)
    except Exception as error:
        command_error = str(error)
        print("Error: "+command_error)

command = "shutdown -h 50"
execute_command(command)
```

Output:

```
['shutdown', '-h', '50']
Command output: 
Command error: Shutdown scheduled for Sat 2018-04-21 19:37:25 +06, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
```

My questions:

1. Why `stdout` is empty?
2. Why the message is shown in `stderr`? Is there any error in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct; the `shutdown` command appears to send its output to stderr:

```
$ shutdown +9 >/dev/null
Shutdown scheduled for Sat 2018-04-21 15:38:00 BST, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
```

whereas `shutdown +9 2>/dev/null` produces no output.

Explanation:

- `>` redirects `stdout` to a file
- `2>` redirects `stderr` to a file
- `/dev/null` is a special file that discards all things written to it

Reference: [TLDP](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Comment: That's relieving! Can you add explanation regarding `>/dev/null` and `2>/dev/null` in the answer?

Comment: For that, I will refer you to [TLDP](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) (in short, `>` redirects stdout to a file, and `2>` redirects stderr to a file; `/dev/null` is a special file that discards all things written to it).

Comment: thank you very much. I updated the answer for future readers.